# .Net code to capture HDMI input from external device

Tags: c#

I have a pet project I want to write that would require a .Net application to be able to capture a video stream from an HDMI input into the PC. I see capture h/w devices out there that will allow for HDMI input, but these normally come with their own software for the client. Is there a h/w appliance that will allow me stream via HDMI into my PC and then capture that stream directly using .Net? Or, is there a different approach that I should be looking for?

The important part is that I want to get the video stream from an external video source that outputs via HDMI into a .Net application on my PC.

Thanks
Neil

Comment: After further research I'm drifting towards any HDMI capture h/w that supports DirectShow. This seems to be the way to go, but further confirmation would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd say this is borderline off-topic - you are asking for hardware recommendations. You might do better on SuperUser.